# Android: Inflate custom layout using <include>

Tags: android, android-layout, include, subclassing

Normally i would expect that i could use a layoutinflator in the constructor (see error below). But the only way to access my **mTitle** is to use **onFinishInflate**. Is this the correct way?

If so, where can i find this in the Android documentation?

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.test.app.widgets.TestLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

</com.test.app.widgets.TestLayout>
```

and my class definition:

```
public class TestLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    TextView mTitle;

    public TestLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

public TestLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TestLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    //Inflate here will result in ResourceNotFound
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (layoutInflater != null) {
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.id.main, this, false);
        mTitle = (TextView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.id.title, this, false);
        mTitle.setText("hioo");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
//This will work!
    mTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    mTitle.setText("This is a test");
}
```

in another XML file i load this layout using:

```
<include layout="@layout/TestLayout" android:id="@+id/test_layout"></include>
```

Error when i use layout inflator in constructor:

```
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.app/com.test.app.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.test.app.widgets.TestLayout
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.test.app.widgets.TestLayout
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at com.test.app.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     ... 11 more
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     ... 26 more
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f05001b type #0x12 is not valid
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:934)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at com.test.app.widgets.TestLayout.<init>(TestLayout.java:41)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     at com.test.app.widgets.TestLayout.<init>(TestLayout.java:33)
02-19 14:35:06.113: E/AndroidRuntime(6535):     ... 29 more
```

Comment: try insted **this(context, null, 0);** change to **super(context);**

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work

Comment: Is this(com.test.app.widgets.TestLayout) correct path check ? And where is  line #2?

Comment: Yes its the correct path. I think thats the textview. It does work when i wait for onFinishInflate(). Same code..